# Proving "proof methods" as theorems in type-theory based proof systems

Tags: coq, type-theory, proof-assistant, metaprogramming

For example, suppose we have proved associativity of some binary operator $+ : T \to T$ as

```ml
add_assoc : forall (x y : T), x + y + z = x + (y + z).
```

We can thus prove the following theorem by repeated application of `add_assoc` with suitable arguments:

```ml
Example forall (x y z w : T), x + ((y + z) + w) = x + y + (z + w).
```

However, no mathematician actually reason about associativity in this way. What we want, intuitively speaking, is a theorem saying that "if $+$ is associative, then you can ignore parentheses". Unfortunately, this syntactical feature is not readily formalizable in proof assistants.

Of course, we can use metalanguages like Ltac and implement this reasoning as a tactic:

```ml
Ltac normalize := repeat rewrite <- add_assoc.
```

However, this is unsatisfying in that we "know" `add_assoc_normalize` *will* work, but this knowledge is not represented within the system. In other words, that we can ignore parentheses remains metatheorem instead of a theorem provable, and thus usable, inside the language.

I am aware that methods like [reflection](http://adam.chlipala.net/cpdt/html/Reflection.html) do help in achieving this, by reifying the syntax trees as `Add x (Add (Add y z) w)`, and having a function `normalize : syntax_tree -> syntax_tree` with a theorem showing that `forall t, interpret (normalize t) = interpret t`. However, since the terms are *reified*, it is arguable that this remains a *metatheorem* that is categorically distinct from theorems like `add_assoc` (and not really usable without resorting to a metalanguage or reifying terms by hand).

Further issues arise for more difficult properties such as commutativity, where there is not necessarily a canonical form to normalize to. However, human mathematicians can still reason about commutativity without explicitly considering which exact sequence of manipulation is necessary.

My questions:

- Right now, is there a way to formalize these sort of theorems in existing proof assistants?
- Are there theoretical frameworks where these sort of theorems can be formalized?
- More speculatively, what do we *mean* by saying that "associativity means parentheses are unimportant" is *true*, when we cannot formalize what we meant by "unimportant"? This statement does seem to have the quality of mathematical truth, in the sense that it "always work" in practice, but how can it be if it cannot be proved from some axioms?

Note: I have focused on proof systems based on type theory because these systems are capable of abstraction *within the system*, whereas systems like LCF seem to have outsourced abstraction to their metalanguage (ML). However, I am interested in any system that allows *internal* abstraction of these sort of "proof methods" into theorems.

Comment: Maybe I am missing your point, but, relative to whichever given language, how can it be *not* a meta-theorem? -- Nor I see how that amounts to "not readily formalizable in proof assistants", especially given that, even with tactics, results are eventually type-checked.

Comment: @JulioDiEgidio My point is tactics exist "outside" the main proof system and thus lacks integration with the rest of the system. For example, we cannot state a theorem that some tactic "ought" to always work, and we cannot prove further theorems based on that fact.

Comment: There is no proper mean of abstraction for these proof methods. While technically we can discard the notion of theorems and always inline the proofs (manually or using some macro preprocessor), the ability to abstract a segment of proof out into a separate reusable theorem is highly useful. So what I am asking is something similar for "proof methods", instead of using some external tactic language (that is essentially a macro preprocessor).

Comment: Do you mean you want to have tactics whose success is guaranteed by a theorem proved inside the prover? Also, what you call "reflection" doesn't seem to be what ordinary programmers refer to as reflection. It looks like it's just usual dependent type programming.

Comment: @Trebor That and additionally representing tactics as tangible entities that can be reasoned about would be a good start, but ultimately what I am looking for is some alternative approach that does not rely on explicit reification, since humans do not really seem to reason this way; or alternatively some intuition on how humans *are* indeed reasoning this way, just that I am not recognizing.

Comment: In other words, I am looking for a formal treatment of such "meta truths" (e.g., some tactic *ought* to always work) without excessive overhead, since in practice humans seem to be able to reason about them without such overhead. Given that in practice humans reason about these "meta truth" in a similar manner as non-meta theorems, this suggests that maybe we can have a uniform treatment in formal proof systems too.

Comment: @Trebor I added a link about what do I mean by reflection in this context.

Comment: Maybe an even better example than associativity is "truth is invariant under changes of notation", where trivial changes such as permuting subscripts seem to reliably produce major headache in formal proof systems.

Comment: I believe what you're asking is impossible, but I also reject your assumption: "this is not how mathematicians think." How mathematician's think is definitely up for debate, but I would not say they "just ignore the parenthesis" and would instead say that they implicitly normalize. You could have a system where tactic are internalized, basically a LISP-like proof assistant, but you're still "phasing" the levels of proof and thus one theorem is at the meta of some other expression. This is what I say is unavoidable, if you're reasoning symbolically about syntax, it must be meta imo.

Comment: @AndrewMarmaduke You should definitely expand on (possibly hypothetical) lisp based system in an answer, especially if there are ways to handle binders without too much pain.